# Login-Signup-Navbar Jquery Not working well

Tags: jquery

Gurus,

I'm trying to have both login and signup together in the navbar. When I have only the login script, jquery works as expected (show on click, hide on click, hide on click anywhere else on the screen).

When I duplicate the script for signup, the show, hide on click dont work well. I've created a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/jsplayground/V63DG/. Please help look into this. I believe the problem is with the jquery. The code below works perfectly for just login.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#login-trigger').click(function(){
    $(this).next('#login-content').toggle();
    $(this).toggleClass('active');                  
    return false;
});

$('#login-content').click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
});
$(document).click(function() {
    $('#login-content').hide();
    $(this).removeClass('active');
}); 
});
```

Comment: i've tried your fiddle and it seems to be working fine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about: [**JSfiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/V63DG/1/) its your fiddle I just updated it with a more reliable approach.

jQuery Code I used:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$('#signup-trigger').click(function(){
    if($('#login-content').is(":visible")) //check if second box is visible
        $('#login-content').slideUp(function(){ //if it is hide it and remove active class
            if($('#signup-content').is(":visible")) //after hiding finished - display selected
                $('#signup-content').slideUp().removeClass('active');
            else
               $('#signup-content').slideDown().addClass('active');            
                }).removeClass('active');
    else
        if($('#signup-content').is(":visible")) // if selected box is visible
            $('#signup-content').slideUp().removeClass('active'); // hide it
        else
           $('#signup-content').slideDown().addClass('active'); //show it 
    return false;
});

$('#login-trigger').click(function(){
    if($('#signup-content').is(":visible")) 
        $('#signup-content').slideUp(function(){
            if($('#login-content').is(":visible"))
                $('#login-content').slideUp().removeClass('active');
            else
               $('#login-content').slideDown().addClass('active');           
        }).removeClass('active');
    else
        if($('#login-content').is(":visible"))
            $('#login-content').slideUp().removeClass('active');
        else
           $('#login-content').slideDown().addClass('active');
    return false;
});

$(document).click(function(){ //hiding boxes when clicking outside
    $('#login-content').slideUp().removeClass('active');
    $('#signup-content').slideUp().removeClass('active');
});
$('#signup-content').click(function(e) { //do something when button clicked 
    e.stopPropagation();
});

$('#login-content').click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
});

});
```

If you preffer hide() and show() - > replace **slideUp** with **hide** and **slideDown** with **show**
Or you can use **fadeIn** and **fadeOut** too...

Have Fun